# bash script command to inject a schema.sql into mysql db

Tags: mysql, bash

i found this code but do not quite understand what the command is doing.

```
sudo -u test-user mysql -U test_traffic traffic < ./phoenix/data/sql/lib.model.schema.sql
```

i know the last part is using lib.model.schema.sql to create the tables and fields
the first part i dont quite understand: `sudo -u test-user mysql -U test_traffic traffic`

i know the command `sudo` and `mysql`

please explain?
thanks

Comment: Is database is created and you want to run script for table schema?

Comment: yes have a database just want to use schema.sql for tables

Comment: What exactly do you want to do ? Is your goal to inject a SQL file in your DB using a bash script or just to understand what this script does ?

Comment: If you understand `sudo` and `mysql` then what's left to explain? `sudo -u` switches to another system user (not root) and `mysql -U` similarly selects a MySQL user name.

Comment: both what does -U stand for then after that i have the database name = test_traffic and then is "traffic" the host? i run the script with this line and i get: [sudo] password for helloises: 
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.41, for debian-linux-gnu (i486) using readline 6.1
Copyright 2000-2008 MySQL AB, 2008 Sun Microsystems, Inc.
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software,
and you are welcome to modify and redistribute it under the GPL license
Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]
as if it shows the "help" menu so something aint right with that line, thanks

Comment: `-U` is different than `-u` ! `-U` is like `--safe-updates` and permit only UPDATE and DELETE statements that specify which rows to modify by using key values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at it bit by bit.  Firstly the format

```
sudo -u username command
```

is an instruction to run `command` (which might be simple or complex) as the user `username`.  So in your example, you are running the `mysql` command as the user `test-user`.  You should note that this includes all the parameters to the `mysql` command - that's the entire rest of the line.

The command

```
mysql -U test_traffic traffic < ./phoenix/data/sql/lib.model.schema.sql
```

appears corrupt (certainly running it on 5.0.51a fails).  It would make sense if the `-U` was a `-u` which would indicate that that the command was to be executed for mysql user `test_traffic`.  If it was a `-u` you would then have an instruction to import the sql file into the traffic database.

So the combined instruction says, import the `lib.model.schema.sql` file into the database `test_traffic` using the mysql user `test_traffic` and executing the entire command as if you were logged-in as the user `test-user`.

Answer (score 2):

Try Below steps for mysql:

```
   mysql > -h hostname  -u username -p password

    mysql > use databasename;

    mysql > source path/to/scriptfile
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to inject theschema.sql file into your database, with a shell script, simply use :

```
mysql -h [host] -u [username] -p[password] -D [database] < your_file
```

If you want to dynamicly tell which file should be loaded, replace `your_file` by `$1` and pass the name of the file as an argument to your script.

Take care also to the `-p` option. There is no space between the `-p` and your password.